# Is there anyway to set up a default location to reference libraries from as well as include in launch.json file for Java projects in VS Code

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner learning Java FX and JDBC, so I frequently create new projects to try stuff out. However every time I create a new java project, I have to add my reference libraries (jar files) again, as well as set up my `launch.json` file to include the necessary vm-args (for Java FX).

This is pretty tedious so I was wondering if there was a way to automate these things when I create a new java project.

referenced libraries
[image: referenced libraries]
launch.json file
[image: launch.json file]

Comment: Please include text like json formatted as code. Do not take screenshots of code and text.  Even directory structures can be shown as text with a tree command.

Comment: I don't know VS code, but you can certainly do this in Idea and other common IDEs.

Comment: VS code has [maven support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build), with other IDEs, they can configure the project libraries by synching with the maven project. Perhaps VS code can do the same.

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please

Answer (score 0):

To the `vmargs` in launch.json, you may put it in **User** Settings:

```
"java.debug.settings.vmArgs": "--"
```

About referenced libraries, you may get them by

```
 "java.project.referencedLibraries": [//"all your needed javafx jars]
```

in workspace settings and paste it to your new created project, which avoid choosing jars and adding them to referenced Libraries.